Does do-release-upgrade an option like --root?
dpkg has a --root option to install the package in a different root directory. Does do-release-upgrade have a similar option?
The case I have at hand is a computer with Xubuntu 22.04 which has been partially updated to 24.04, but something failed and now some libraries are updated and some are not (such as libc).
My thought was to use a live image, and mount the disk. Then I could just bring all packages up to the version of 24.04, by running do-release-upgrade of the live image, but working on the packages on the disk. This way, the upgrade itself would not need to run in the damaged system.
Is such a thing possible? Would I use a live image of 22.04 or 24.04?

That's not possible. Either fix your damaged system first or go for a fresh install.

The release-upgrade process downloads all that is required, then starts installing the packages (in a specific order in some cases; so its more than a dist-upgrade alone) but your details imply the upgrade of packages has already started; meaning you fix [normally] using normal package commands; ie. apt update (read output & base what you do by its output! ie. did recovery occur or not? etc), apt full-upgrade and any other commands required due to problem.. you don't run do-release-upgrade again.  I'd not do that using live, but your installed system directly; text terminal only!

Just an FYI; but running a release-upgrade on a 24.04 system would tell the system to upgrade to 24.10 assuming you've applied updates that could prevent upgrade & allowed non-LTS upgrades (a live system may require use of a daily rather than older released ISO; but I just tested a 24.04.1 daily & upgrade was offered on my live) and of course non-LTS upgrades were allowed otherwise it'll error that no LTS upgrade is available; that'll open after release of 26.04.1 second half 2026; jammy to noble is history in regards that tool, from your question description.

@guiverc That procedure had occurred to me, but apt is one of the broken commands... strangely enough not all shell commands are broken though, but many are. Bash itself is working. Perhaps I can add the new libc from a 24.04 live system, hopefully repairing apt and others, and then follow along your procedure. /var/cache/apt/archive contains what appears to be versions from 24.04 (at least libc and related, so probably all(?) others as well).
